# Pace.js using dropdown list box

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-typeahead, pace

is it possible  where we can able to use the pace.js while I'm  clicking the items in drop down list box
is this is possible

Comment: <script>
  $(document).on('change','#lobID', function(e) {
  pace.start();
  });

 </script>

Comment: Any update on the above quieries